# Grabbing existing session on page reload with express/connect-redis

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node.js-connect

Using connect, express, and socket.io, I'm trying to allow my application to grab the session details when reconnecting. My sessions obviously work while the client is connected, but if I refresh the page on my browser, it forgets everything.
My session cookie is definitely the same, so it's not that.

My code's a big mish-mash of snippets I've taken from a number of different sources, since there doesn't seem to be one complete example application out there.

What am I missing..?

```
var qs      = require('querystring'),
    express = require('express'),
    app     = express.createServer(),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8000)),
    routes  = require('./routes'),
    pCookie = require('connect').utils.parseCookie,
    Session = require('connect').middleware.session.Session,
    RedStore= require('connect-redis')(express),
    sStore  = new RedStore();
   
// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ store: sStore, secret: 'tehsecretz' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    var hs = client.handshake,
        session = hs.session;

    console.log('A socket connected called: ' + hs.sessionId);

    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        hs.session.reload(function() {
            hs.session.touch().save();
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);

    if (!session.userName) {
        // Prompts the user for a name on the frontend
        client.emit('need-to-register');
    }

    client.on('message', function(msg, c) {
        console.log(session);
        console.log(msg);
    });

    client.on('register-user', function(data, fn) {
        // This retrieves the user's name
        // and - hopefully - saves it to the session.

        data = qs.parse(data);
        session.userName = data.username;

        hs.session.save();
        console.log('Saving: ', session);

        fn('ok');
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
});

io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        data.cookie = pCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionId = data.cookie['connect.sid'];

        data.sessionStore = sStore;
        sStore.get(data.sessionId, function (err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                accept('Error', false);
            } else {
                console.log(data.sessionId, session);
                data.session = new Session(data, session);
                accept(null, true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        return accept('No cookie transmitted', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: The simple answer is that Socket.IO is not connect, and bodyParser only acts on connect requests. Socket.IO has different transports, and they don't share cookies, so it would have to beusing one of the HTTP transports, and you would need middleware for Socket.IO that can sumbit a session cookie to connect, or use the connect session API to retrieve the session.

Comment: But `sStore` is an instance of `connect-redis`, so wouldn't the `sStore.get()` within the `authorization` method be the way to handle that? Like I said, it's not like the cookie is changing at all; in my head, I would have thought that updating the session (from `client.on('register-user'...)`) would write it to redis, and therefore be available by the cookie upon retrieval. ....unless I'm missing something basic, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh. So in [Daniel Baulig's post](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) on the subject, he referenced the identifier `sessionID`. I figured that was just poor convention (as I'm used to camelCase) and promptly changed it to `sessionId` in my code.

As I was debugging, I turned on `MONITOR`ing on my redis instance and noticed the session was being written to `sess:undefined`.

Turns out `sessionID` is special and is referenced internally as the actual identifier. Changing all instances of `sessionId` to `sessionID` allows me to have a better clue as to who is connecting!

Answer (score 1):

Add 'cookie' in "express.session"

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'exampleSecretKey'
    ,store: exampleStore
    ,key: 'example'
    cookie: {
        path: '/'
        ,expires: false // Alive Until Browser Exits
        ,httpOnly: true
    //  ,domain:'.example.com'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this had no effect.